# Installed HTTPD and PHP from remi, PHP not exciting, no errors written to the error log

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

Currently no errors anywhere, when I visit a php page in my browser, it just outputs the php code to the browser,

I have a .htaccess file with the following

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

php still not running, php -v shows php installed: 
PHP 5.3.10 (cli) (built: Feb  4 2012 07:36:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

I just need to get apache to execute the php code.

Comment: `php -v` shows the CLI version of PHP.  Could you check that Apache knows about the PHP extension with `apache2ctl -M`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have php installed try to create php configuration in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

It should be included by default on redhat like distros. (you can check it yourself if you have Include conf.d/*.conf in your httpd.conf.

Adding this sort of configuration to .htaccess is not a best idea imo and should be staticly placed in *.conf files... are you sure that AllowOverride is not set to None?